# Perl + Linux rearranging columns in a multiple text places

Tags: linux, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file;
my @files;
my $parse;
my @files = <*>;
foreach $file(@files)
 chomp ($file);
{
 $parse = system qq(paste <(cut -f1,2,13 $file) <(cut -f12 $file));
}
```

---

```
"my" variable @files masks earlier declaration in same scope at Rast_seq.pl line 11.
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Please help me fix this error.

Comment: It would be good if you showed sample input/output. It's quite redundant to use shell commands for this, I suspect, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. It's quite silly of you to use `qq()` when parentheses occur in the string and double quotes don't. This is a source of trouble for you.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do. You're using Perl, and then calling a system command. Is `$parse` suppose to contain something interesting? The only thing it will contain is the exit status of your `system` command. Why not simply do the whole thing in Perl or shell? If I think I understand what you're doing, you could do it entirely in shell or Perl and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Move the open brace `{` before the `chomp;`
and remove the first `my @files;`
and change the delimiters of `qq`

```
my $file;
my $parse;
my @files = <*>;

foreach $file(@files) {
    chomp ($file);
    $parse = system qq#paste <(cut -f1,2,13 $file) <(cut -f12 $file)#;
}
```

Comment: And change `qq()` to `""`, because the string contains delimiters.

Comment: @TLP: Yes, of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

Few problems here:

- You are declaring @files array twice;
- `chomp ($file);` is outside `for` block;
- `chomp ($file);` is useless in this situation: `<*>` returns list of file names - you are not reading lines (I would recommend you use `glob '*';` as it is more readable);
- `system` function runs your command using `/bin/sh` which - as it seems - doesn't support `<(...)` construct